# KivyMD How to get value from a dynamic text fields?

Tags: python, kivy, textfield, kivymd

I asked a question last time on how to add a multiple text fields on a button press: [How to add multiple textfield in kivymd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935919/how-to-add-multiple-textfield-in-kivymd/71937374?noredirect=1#comment127137809_71937374). I've done it properly but now im stucked with another problem. My problem now is how to get the value of each added textfields now that they don't have any assigned id. I thought of a workaround on this where I used dialogs to reference the text and then appending it to a dictionary, but I realized that if I edit it on the text field I will not be able to get the changed value. So now i really need to directly reference the values on the added textfields. here is my file. thank you very much!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase


KV = """
ScreenManager:
    FormScreen:
<FormScreen>
    name: 'form'
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color:app.dark2
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            md_bg_color:app.dark2
            title: "Upload Data"
            type_height: "small"
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x : app.swtchScreen('collections')]]
            right_action_items: [["eraser", lambda x : app.add_dict()],["plus", lambda x : app.form_dialog()]]
        MDTabs:
            id: tabs
            background_color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
            tab_hint_x: True
            Tab:
                title: "Passport Data"
                MDBoxLayout: # Add main container.
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: dp(10)
                    spacing: dp(5)
                    MDTextField:
                        id: input_1
                        hint_text: "Name"
#                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.95}
#                        size_hint: .75,0.09 # "size_hint_y" will be set automatically.
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                        size_hint_x: .75
                        color_mode: 'accent'
                        mode: "rectangle"

                    #additional textfields
                    ScrollView:
                        MDBoxLayout: # Add all text fields in this container.
                            id: box
                            orientation: "vertical"
                            adaptive_height: True # Grow vertically.
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        id:title
        hint_text: "Title"

    MDTextField:
        id:desc
        hint_text: "Description"
"""



class FormScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    dark2 = 46/255, 139/255, 87/255, 1
    dict = {}

    def form_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Add Data",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_press = lambda x : self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)

                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="OK",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_press = lambda x : self.add_textfields()
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
    def add_textfields(self):
        self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)
        # self.dialog.content_cls.ids.title.text, self.dialog.content_cls.ids.desc.text = "",""

        title = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.title.text
        desc = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.desc.text
        self.dict[f'{title}'] = f'{desc}'
        print(self.dict)
        self.help.get_screen('form').ids.box.add_widget(
        MDTextField(hint_text= title,
                    text = desc,
                    size_hint = (.75,0.08),
                    mode = "rectangle",
                    color_mode = 'accent',
                    pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5}
        ))
    def build(self):
        # screen =Screen()
        
        self.title='Demeter'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightGreen"   

        self.help = Builder.load_string(KV)
        # screen.add_widget(self.help)
        return self.help

DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: Could you please describe precisely which text field you're referring to in ***'but I realized that if I edit it on the text field I will not be able...'*** ?

Comment: So the program runs like this, press add button > popup dialog > input text in the dialog > get the value from the texfield inside the dialog > add a textfield on the main screen with added values on the dialog. the problem with this is that i am getting the values on the the input text field inside the dialog not on the text field on the main screen. We can scrap the idea of using dialog and just use textfield right away. All i need is to get the value from the text field. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in several ways, one could be like, keeping a reference of the text fields (may be within a list/dict) while adding them to their parent. Another one could be like creating a dynamic attribute to that instances to access it later by an event (prop. callback or event callback).

Following is an implementation of the latter one :

```py
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    dark2 = 46/255, 139/255, 87/255, 1
    dict = {} # Using of default keyword is not recommended. May be 'dict_'.
    # Add a counter.
    count = 0
    .
    .
    .
     
    def add_textfields(self):
        self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)
        # self.dialog.content_cls.ids.title.text, self.dialog.content_cls.ids.desc.text = "",""

        title = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.title.text
        desc = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.desc.text
        self.dict[f'{title}'] = f'{desc}'
        print(self.dict)

        # Make sure to change "count" in order to create
        # unique dynamic attribute each time.
        self.count += 1
        # First create an instance.
        text_field = MDTextField(hint_text= title,
                    text = desc,
                    size_hint = (.75,0.08),
                    mode = "rectangle",
                    color_mode = 'accent',
                    pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5}
        )
        # Add a (valid) dynamic attribute of your choice.
        text_field.tid = self.count
        # I bound it to the event "on_text_validate" by an event callback,
        # say, "do_something" as a demonstration.
        # Use it if you need to.
        text_field.bind(on_text_validate = self.do_something)
        # Now add that instance.
        self.help.get_screen('form').ids.box.add_widget(text_field)
    
    def do_something(self, t_field):
        """This is the (prop. or event) callback."""
        print(f"This is the text from text field with tid  {t_field.tid} :", t_field.text)
    .
    .
    .
```