# Dynamically setting attributes to MDTextField in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivymd

I have code below which dynamically creates a bunch of text fields in KivyMD. However, one attribute I need to set, `on_text`, will not accept my settings through python (no error thrown, just a blank field on debug), but will accept them through KV.

My questions are: Why is it not accepting my on_text update, and how can I work around it programmatically while maintaining python/KV separation?

Here's the python code:

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('./main.kv')
        
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()

        
class PRApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Gray"
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name="home_screen"))

        return self.sm

    def add_rm_textboxes(self):  # sourcery skip: use-fstring-for-concatenation
        for i in range(1,21):
            textbox = MDTextField(hint_text=str(i)+" RM",mode="fill",helper_text="Enter your TESTED "+str(i)+" RM",helper_text_mode="on_focus")
            textbox.on_text = print(textbox.text)
            textbox.name = "rm"+str(i)
            self.sm.current_screen.ids.pr_grid.add_widget(textbox)

    def wait(self):
        pass
            


PRApp().run()
```

And here's my KV code:

```py
<HomeScreen>:
    id: home_screen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDBottomNavigation:

            id: bottom_nav

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'home_screen'
                text: "Home"
                icon: 'home'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "PR!"
                        anchor_title: 'center'

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "This is the home screen"
                        halign: 'center'

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'routine_screen'
                text: "Routines"
                icon: 'notebook'
                on_tab_press: app.wait()

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Routines"
                    halign: 'center'


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'profile_screen'
                text: "Profile"
                icon: 'account-circle-outline'
                on_tab_press: app.add_rm_textboxes()

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Profile"
                    halign: 'center'


                MDGridLayout:
                    id: pr_grid
                    cols: 2
```

Comment: Did you try binding with text ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72005145/kivymd-how-to-get-value-from-a-dynamic-text-fields/72015603#72015603) answer to your question ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not as far as I can tell. When I test it by adding a simple test print to the add_rm_textboxes method, I get the error shown below.

Code:
`textbox.bind(on_text = print('test'))`

Error:
`Exception has occurred: AssertionError
None is not callable
  File "F:\Docs\GitHub\Kivy-project\project.py", line 32, in add_rm_textboxes
    textbox.bind(on_text = print('test'))
  File "F:\Docs\GitHub\Kivy-project\main.kv", line 40, in <module>
    on_tab_press: app.add_rm_textboxes()
  File "F:\Docs\GitHub\Kivy-project\project.py", line 42, in <module>
    PRApp().run()`

Comment: You should've done `textbox.bind(text=some_method_or_function)`.

Comment: Tried that and got the same result, unfortunately. My code: `textbox.bind(text = print("test"))` results in the same 'None is not callable' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you [bind](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=bind#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) a callback to an event or a property that callback is supposed to be a function / method (name) not what it returns. That's why you got `None` when you did [`textbox.bind(text = print("test"))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143178/need-to-dynamically-set-attributes-in-a-kivymd-mdtextfield/72147134#comment127474684_72143178), you could've done it like, `textbox.bind(text = lambda *args : print("test"))`. Also note that a property callback is different from an event callback in kivy.

Here is a modified version of that portion,

```py
    def add_rm_textboxes(self):  # sourcery skip: use-fstring-for-concatenation
        for i in range(1,21):
            textbox = MDTextField(hint_text=str(i)+" RM",mode="fill",helper_text="Enter your TESTED "+str(i)+" RM",helper_text_mode="on_focus")
            textbox.bind(text = self.callback_method)
#            textbox.bind(text = lambda *args : print("test"))
            textbox.name = "rm"+str(i)
            self.sm.current_screen.ids.pr_grid.add_widget(textbox)


    def callback_method(self, txtbx, txt):
        print(f"{txtbx.text = }, {txt = }, {txtbx.name = }")
```

Comment: Ok, I have a few questions, as I am pretty new to kivy. First, the result I am looking for is to set the on_text method, so that when the text field is modified, the class calls a function I have in the app. I used print functions in this example code because I thought it made no difference what I used (since I got the same error either way). The function in my real code doesn't output anything, it retrieves the 'text' value from the text box. This looks like this code is for the 'text' attribute, which fills out the text in the box. For on_text, does the process differ?

Comment: Second, the print function obviously has an output, but the output goes to standard out (screen), not the class, right?

Comment: After testing the code, modifying the 'text' attribute like this seems to actually set the callback for the on_text method, but I don't understand why?

Comment: Please have a look at the link attached to the answer. Also note that in `kvlang` event callback can easily be made by using a prefix [**`on_`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html?highlight=on_prop#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords) before a property, which is different in python during binding.